# How do I make a JOptionPane dropdown that has a preset option that is not choosable?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Say I am making a program that keeps track of people's favorite food. I have a dropdown, as such:

```
String foods = { "Pizza", "Burgers", "Pasta", "Bacon" };
String favoriteFood = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your favorite food?", "Choice", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, foods, foods[0]));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, favoriteFood);
```

How do I make a part in the dropdown that is like "Choose now...", but if you click the "Choose now...", it doesn't become your choice? Thank you!

Comment: You roll your own dialog

Comment: I don't think you can do that easily with a `JOptionPane`. But why not create your own `JDialog`, with a custom `JComboBox`, in combination with a custom renderer as shown here:  https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/combo-box-prompt/.

Comment: Alright. Thank you!

Comment: 1) Read the JOptionPane API. There is code that shows you the "Direct Use" of the JOptionPane class so you have access to the `JOptionPane` component. 2) Check out: [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/). If will show you how to access the combo box of the JOptionPane. 3) set the renderer of the combo box as described by the link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it like this

```java
String[] foods = { "Pizza", "Burgers", "Pasta", "Bacon" };
JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(foods);
cb.getModel().setSelectedItem("Choose now...");

cb.addHierarchyListener(hEv -> {
    if((hEv.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0 && cb.isShowing()) {
        JButton ok = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(cb).getDefaultButton();
        ok.setEnabled(cb.getSelectedIndex() >= 0);
        cb.addActionListener(aEv -> ok.setEnabled(cb.getSelectedIndex() >= 0));
}   });

JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 8));
p.add(new JLabel("What is your favorite food?"));
p.add(cb);

int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
    p, "Choice", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    choice == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION? cb.getSelectedItem(): "no choice");
```

The first challenge is to set a (pre)selected value that is not part of the selectable choices. When you call `setSelectedItem` on a non-editable `JComboBox`, it will reject any values outside the model. However, we can set the selected value on the model directly, like in `cb.getModel().setSelectedItem("Choose now...");`

Then, to ensure that we won’t confuse this initial selection with an actual selection, we have to disable the “Ok” button until a choice from the list has been made (`cb.getSelectedIndex() >= 0`). To get the “Ok” button itself, we wait until the entire AWT hierarchy has been constructed and get the default button.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using the `JOptionPane` is shown below. In this code the `JDialog` is more or less manually created. The OK button and available options are then pulled from the `JOptionPane` and the OK button is only enabled when anything other than 'Choose from...' is selected.

```
String[] foods = new String[]{"Choose now...", "Pizza", "Burgers", "Pasta", "Bacon"};
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("What is your favorite food?",  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null,
        null, null);

pane.setWantsInput(true);
pane.setSelectionValues(foods);
pane.setInitialSelectionValue(foods[0]);

// create the dialog and select the initial value
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog( null, "title" );
pane.selectInitialValue();

// find the OK Button and disable it by default
JPanel buttonPanel = (JPanel) pane.getComponent( 1 );
JButton ok = (JButton) buttonPanel.getComponent( 0 );
ok.setEnabled( false );
// find the JComboBox (the panel holding the available options)
JPanel childPanel = (JPanel) ((JPanel) pane.getComponent( 0 )).getComponent( 0 );
JPanel innerPanel = (JPanel) childPanel.getComponent( 1 );
JComboBox options = (JComboBox) innerPanel.getComponent( 1 );
// add an action listener to the JComboBox; enable the OK button if a valid option is selected
options.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( options.getSelectedIndex() == 0 ) {
            ok.setEnabled( false );
        } else {
            ok.setEnabled( true );
        }
    }
});

// show the dialog
dialog.show(); // <--- note this one is deprecated, should probably use: dialog.setVisible( true );
dialog.dispose();

// get the selected value
String value = pane.getInputValue().toString();
```